# Django : Unsupported format character '''

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I add this model to my **models.py**

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    id_doc = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, verbose_name='Nom du document')
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to="files/", blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Chemin vers le fichier")

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'documents'
        verbose_name = u'Document'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Documents'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.id_doc)
```

And  in **admin.py**

```
class DocumentsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Documents
    inline_classes = ('grp-collapse grp-open')
    extra = 1
    fk_name = 'name'
```

I don't know why, but when i try to execute `makemigrations`, I have this issue :

```
<class 'newPrpvApp.admin.DocumentsInline'>: (admin.E202) unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 41
```

Can you help me to fix this error please ? ty

Comment: No, `inline_classes = ('grp-collapse grp-open')` it does not seem to be a problem because it works in other places. However, I tried, and the error is always the same.

Comment: Will replacing `u'%s' % (self.id_doc)` with `u'{0}'.format(self.id_doc)` solve the problem?

Comment: I solve the probleme deleting `fk_name`. I dont know if it's a good choice :X

Comment: `inline_classes = ('grp-collapse grp-open')` should be `inline_classes = ('grp-collapse grp-open',)` as it expects a tuple. May be that is the issue ?